# Get Javascript cookie in ASP MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I created a javasrcipt cookie in a View and when `#btn` is clicked, the ajax method sends the value to `SomeAction` in the Home Controller.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#select').change(function(){
           document.cookie = "myCookie=myCookieVal";
        });

        $('#btn').click(function(){
           $.post('/Home/SomeAction', function(){
               // some code
           })
        });            
    })
</script>
```

Here is the Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies["myCookie"] != null)
        {
         // some stuff
        }
    }
```

My problem is that I can't get the value of `myCookie` in the Controller Action.

What should I do to get the cookie value in the Controller?

Comment: Why dont you create your cookie with c# instead ? create an ajax func that send a create command with its value

Comment: it's more likely you don't get in the SELECT.change function ?